# Second class is throwing Null Pointer exception for TestNG

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I've created different classes for each webpage using TestNG. My first class is working fine but the second class is throwing Null Pointer Exception. The same script if I combine in only one class It's working without any issues.

Below is my baseclass

```
package Test;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import Pages.FM_login;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
public class Baseclass {
  WebDriver driver;
  FM_login  objLogin;
  @BeforeTest
  public void setup() {
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\****\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe");
        String url = "http://vatlookup.cloudfront.net";
          driver = new ChromeDriver();
          driver.manage().window().maximize();
          driver.get(url);
          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          String Title = driver.getTitle();
          System.out.println(Title);
          System.out.println("Application Launch successful");
          // Accept the cookie policy
          driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='cc-btn cc-allow']")).click();
  }
  @Test
  public void Login() {
      objLogin = new FM_login(driver);
      objLogin.GoToLoginScreen();
      objLogin.loginToFleetMatch("abc", "123");
      System.out.println("Login Successful");
  }
 @AfterTest(enabled=false)
  public void teardown() {
      driver.close();
}
```

This is another class

```
package Test;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import Pages.FM_Profile;

public class Profile {
    WebDriver driver;
    FM_Profile objProfile;
    
    
     @Test
      public void Skip_Tutorial() {
          objProfile = new FM_Profile(driver);
          driver.getCurrentUrl();
          objProfile.SkipTutorial();
      }
      
      @Test(enabled=false)
      public void edit_profile() {
          objProfile.edit_profile();
      }
}
```

below is the page object for a second class

```
package Pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class FM_Profile {
    
    WebDriver driver;
    By company_name = By.xpath("//p[@id='company-name']");
    By plan_details = By.xpath("//p[@id='current-plan']");
    By End_tour = By.xpath("//button[@class='driver-close-btn']");
    By edit_profile = By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Edit')]");
    By Description = By.xpath("//textarea[@id='mat-input-10']");
    By Upload_image = By.xpath("//div[@class='upload-btn continental-book ng-star-inserted']");
    By Save_profile = By.xpath("//button[@class='save-btn continental-book mat-stroked-button mat-button-base mat-primary editMode cdk-focused cdk-mouse-focused']");
    
    
    public FM_Profile(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }
    
    public void SkipTutorial() {
        driver.findElement(End_tour).click();
    }
```

after executing it's showing java.lang.NullPointerException for second class

error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Test.Profile.Skip_Tutorial(Profile.java:16)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:135)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:598)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:174)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:821)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:147)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1507)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:588)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1214)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1136)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1066)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1034)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Comment: Unrelated, yet important: you should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variabele names and method names should be written in camelCase and class names in PascalCase.

Answer (score 0):

In your Profile class the driver object is not initialized. The driver object that you are initializing is in BaseClass and instance of that class. You need to initialize driver object in Profile class as well

Answer (score 0):

WebDriver is never initialised.

WebDriver driver = new WebDriver();

Comment: It's showing error, I've given WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot instantiate class Test.Profile